# Error: a 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}'). What is wrong?

Tags: function, return, expression

I have an error *"a 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')"* in a code snippet:

```
fun validateMove(nam: String): Boolean {
    for (i in 1..8) {
    if (nam == first) {
        if (Regex("[a-h][0-9][a-h][0-9]").matches(turn)) { return true
    } else { return false }
    } else if (Regex("[i-m][0-9][i-m][0-9]").matches(turn)) { return true
      } else return false
} 
}
```

I tried to use several modifications of this code, did it in other variants with different position of "{}", but it still doesn't work. I have no idea what problem is. Will be very thankfull if somebody can help me.

Comment: You need to include a tag for the programming language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

There is no return outside the for so if the for does 0 loop (I know its not supposed to happen here but that's how computers think), there won't be any returns. I you create a variable 'result', and store the result in it and then, at the very end of the function put a return result, it should work.

(If I read your function correctly, it is supposed to return something on the first loop so I don't really understand why there is a loop here.)